# How to improve the system performance

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, performance

I'm really frustrated and need some expert help. I'm using Hp Pavilion dv6910tx laptop having 3 G.B. of RAM and 320 Hard -disk. And, I'm using Windows7 professional OS (for more than a year). Since, last 2 months, its response is very slow and took 15-20 min for starting up. I used all the the possible way to improve the system performance like:

1. Hard disk Defragment
2. Disk Check
3. Full scan using Microsoft Essential.

But, still facing same problem, even when I look my CPU usage, it always shows between 0-10%. I don't understand why it is responding very slowly.

Comment: How much space is alloted to page file? Paging is very crucial to performance on Windows systems. Check the size of pagefile.sys in your C: and D: drives to know that.

Comment: how to find this ???

Comment: How full is your hard disk ?  As hard drives get fuller (over 80-90% typically) they slow down, although a disk defrag should help a bit as you have done.  Have you looked at using a registry cleaner like CCleaner ?

Comment: use bootmgr to trace why Windows boots slowly: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140247

Comment: @davidgo around 60-70% full. and if your saying do registry cleaning, then let me try that one also.

Comment: The pagefile.sys is in your root directories for eg: C:\pagefile.sys and D:\pagefile.sys. Another way is to open "Control-Panel=>System=>Advanced system settings" and look in the Advanced tab.

Comment: @jWeavers have you done the boot tracing?

Comment: install SSD and use 320 Hard -disk as external HDD :)

Comment: Have you checked the usage of your system's memory? If that's congested, it could be indicative of PUPs (probably unwanted programs) on your box.

Answer (score 1):

Use CCleaner Which is the best System cleaning and optimizing tool , it clears all the temp files and cleans registry,etc. Malwarebytes for Malware scanning and cleanning.

Comment: I tried all, but facing same problem, even i freed up drive (deleted 30 g.b. from Hard drive). But, no improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I've have seen programs like virus scanners and file backup programs that slow things down tremendously without major CPU usage; especially on restart.  If it happened 2 months ago, what software changed 2 months ago?  Try to identify the program and either eliminate it, optimize its settings, or get rid of it and find an alternative.  Or, try to roll back to a system restore from 2 months ago to before when it was faster, then incrementally move forward with programs and MS updates.

Answer (score 1):

Abnormally slow boot times may be indicative of a failing hard drive.  Some things to check:

Event Log (system) for disk errors.
From a command prompt: chkdsk c: /f, reboot, and let it run.  If it reports bad sectors then your drive is dying.
The BIOS may also have a built in disk verification utility

Answer (score 0):

I would run a Hard Drive diagnostic, either http://www.hgst.com/hdd/support/downloads/dft32_v416_b00.iso or http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/item/seatools-dos-master/ and burn it to a disc and check.  If the hard drive is running good, try using msconfig to remove unnecessary startup items.  Too many items running can hurt performance.  If all  fails, consider upgrading your hard drive to an SSD for the OS and store other items on a different hard drive.  That was single handedly the best upgrade I've ever made on a computer for performance.